# Nested expression, how should I get the value

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I'm trying to parse things like this:

```
where length matches "5000" (status matches "200" OR status matches "302")

where
    : WHERE whereExpression
    ;

whereExpression
    : Identifier MATCHES StringLiteral
    | LPAREN whereExpression RPAREN
    | whereExpression AND whereExpression
    | whereExpression OR  whereExpression
    ;
WHERE: 'where' ;
```

Now if I need to get the value of `Identifier` and `StringLiteral` I could just use the `$` stuff.

But how can I get the value from the `whereExpression AND whereExpression` pattern?

I've been thinking about replacing it with `Identifier MATCHES StringLiteral AND Identifier MATCHES StringLiteral`

But in that case I would have two variables with the same name.

What's the right solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add labels to your matched subexpressions:

```
whereExpression
: Identifier MATCHES StringLiteral #whereMatches
| LPAREN whereExpression RPAREN   # whereParens
| lhsAnd = whereExpression AND rhsAnd = whereExpression   #whereAnd
| lhsOr = whereExpression OR  rhsOr = whereExpression #whereOr
;
```

See [documentation](https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR4/Parser+Rules) for more information.

Or you could split the rule up into several rules

```
whereExpression
: whereMatches
| whereParens
| whereAnd
| whereOr
;


whereMatches : Identifier MATCHES StringLiteral;
whereParens : LPAREN whereExpression RPAREN;
whereAnd : lhs = whereExpression AND rhs = whereExpression;
whereOr : lhs = whereExpression OR  rhs = whereExpression;
```

In any way you can get the value for the expression at the desired position/subrule.